# efficiency of JasDB on Android

Tags: android, jasdb

Are there any benchmarks measuring efficiency of JasDB on Android? Lacking those, is there some (noSQL-)DB-benchmark that could be adapted?

The [JasDB API](https://github.com/oberasoftware/jasdb/wiki/Java-Client-API) seems like a good fit for JSON-document storage in android.

Yet, it internally uses Guice, among others, whose use is
  discouraged by Google because of performance and memory issues. (See
  the `androidlibs`-folder in [the archive](https://github.com/oberasoftware/jasdb/releases/download/1.1.2-8/jasdb_1.1.2.zip), which is to be used
  wholesale

> The libraries for using Android are provided in the Enterprise
>       download in the folder called 'androidlibs'. These libraries
>       should be deployed with your Android Application.)